# Graph consistency depending on orientdb conflict strategy

Tags: orientdb

On this page the different conflict strategies are described: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Alter-Database.html

If we select "content" och "automerge", can we be certain that graph consistency is maintained?

For example, if two threads create two different edges concurrently to the same vertex (ignoring transactions). If one thread overwrites the in_E[] property of the vertex we will end up with a unidirectional edge.

---

UPDATE:
Just to clearify: optimistic conurrency is only the case if we have conflict stragety set to "version", right? Does that also mean that if we use "content" or "automerge" we might end up with broken linkes/edges unless we write our own locks on record? What is the point of these strategies in that case?

Answer (score 0):

In OrientDB the concurrency is managed with an optimistic approach. (see [link](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Concurrency.html))
If there aren't interferences, because well managed by the developer, the graph will consistent.

Comment: Just to clearify: optimistic conurrency is only the case if we have conflict stragety set to "version", right? Does that also mean that if we use "content" or "automerge" we might end up with broken linkes/edges unless we write our own locks on record? What is the point of these strategies in that case?